# SQL Server - loop through table and update based on count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server database. I need to loop through a table to get the count of each value in the column 'RevID'. Each value should only be in the table a certain number of times - for example 125 times. If the count of the value is greater than 125 or less than 125, I need to update the column to ensure all values in the RevID (are over 25 different values) is within the same range of 125 (ok to be a few numbers off)

For example, the count of RevID = "A2" is = 45 and the count of RevID = 'B2' is = 165 then I need to update RevID so the 45 count increases and the 165 decreases until they are within the 125 range.

This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1,
        @RevCnt INT = SELECT RevId, COUNT(RevId) FROM MyTable group by RevId

WHILE(@RevCnt >= 50)
BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable 
    SET RevID= (SELECT COUNT(RevID) FROM MyTable) 
    WHERE RevID < 50)

    @i = @i + 1       
END
```

I have also played around with a cursor and instead of trigger. Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Your update doesn't make sense. It will just update the same rows over and over. And honestly you don't need a loop of any kind to do simple updates. What we need though is to understand what you are actually trying to do. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is `RevId` values strings like "A2" or "B2" or are they integers ? cause if they are strings then you can't update them to the va;lue of a `count(*)`, and you can't have a where clause that filters only the rows where `RevId < 50`.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to 'balance' a table so each value appears only a certain number of times. If you don't care what the original value of a row was this should be relatively easy.

Comment: Show us the schema for this table!

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense that is why I am asking for help. Wouldn't I need to loop through the data to do the update? As you can tell, I am not an SQL developer.

Comment: What is the best approach to balance the value in that column? The value is a string. I am not trying to update the value with the count - just with the value within the count.

Comment: The problem is I don't even know what you mean by balance... even in the two lines of explanation you give in the question you seemed to get the numbers 45, 165, 25 and 65 mixed up -- or maybe I don't understand.  At the very least the one line example you give needs to make sense before you can figure out how to apply these rules.

Comment: I echo a few other question, what do you mean by balance perhaps you can go back and edit your question with a better description of how you would like to balance.  Do you want all RevId values to be represented evenly?  Only modified if over 125 and then evenly????????

Comment: For example: say the count of "A2" in column RevID is = 45 and the count of "B2" in the column RevID = 165. I need to update RevID so the 45 count increases and the 165 decreases until they are within the 125 count range. I fixed my post. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: stating the same thing over and over isn't going to get you what you want.  you need to try a different example/narrative. we all know you want to increase the 45 and decrease the 165 but what we don't know is what the outcome of your example would be.  Would after balancing A2 count = 85 and B2 = 125?  I can only assume that might be what you want because 45 and 165 are with in 125 of each other already

Comment: Matt, Yes! The RevID value needs to be evenly represented. If it is over or under the 125 it needs to be updated. Another example: lets say I have 25 possible RevID values. They all need to be in the table the same number of times. Thanks for all input.

Comment: The problem is I don't even know what you mean by balance...   you seem to be saying you want it to be 125 -- ones less than that need more and ones more than that need less.  That isn't balance that is 125.  Maybe be you mean "normalize to 125"?

Comment: evenly represented then the final would be a2 = 105 and b2 = 105 not the 85 and 125 I suggested.  But now that they are 105 they are still under 125 so you want them to be adjusted again because they are under 125? When do you decide when the are balanced evenly?  I give up, I know how to write the sQL to shift the counts change etc, but you obviously don't get that we are here to help.  We are not defining your business rules or telling you what you should do for something to be even.  That is what we want to receive from you.

Comment: I am trying to get each value in the RevID column to be in the table the same number of times. The numbers I gave were just an example. I do get that your here to help - that is why I posted on this site. I just wanted some input from SQL developers that know  more than I do about SQL.

Comment: 1st question. Let's your table consists of n rows and has m different RevIds. How you want to "balance" your table if `n % m != 0` (not divides without remaining)

2nd question. Case of 2 different RevIds isn't yet clear - if count of 'a2' > count of 'b2' what a2 rows can be selected to change them to 'b2'.

3rd question. Case of >3 different RevIds is less clear at all. What RevId should balance what other RevId? What rows of specific RevId?

Seems your task is bad specified, @user2448412.

Comment: it seems you need to insert/delete rows in your table instead of updating. something like if you have a count of a2 revids = 45 insert 80 rows with revis a2 to make the count 125.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I cam back to this because I found it interesting even though clearly there are some business rules/discussion that you and I and others are not seeing.  anyway, if you want to evenly and distribute arbitrarily there are a few ways you could do it by building recursive Common Table Expressions [CTE] or by building temp tables and more.  Anyway here is a way that I decided to give it a try, I did utilize 1 temp table because sql was throwing in a little inconsistency with the main logic table as a cte about every 10th time but the temp table seems to have cleared that up.  Anyway, this will evenly spread RevId arbitrarily and randomly assigning any remainder (# of Records / # of RevIds) to one of the RevIds.  This script also doesn't rely on having a UniqueID or anything it works dynamically over row numbers it creates.....  here you go just subtract out test data etc and you have what you more than likely want.  Though rebuilding the table/values would probably be easier.

```
--Build Some Test Data
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (RevId VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @C AS INT = 1
WHILE @C <= 400
BEGIN

    IF @C <= 200
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Table (RevId) VALUES ('A1')
    END

    IF @c <= 170
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Table (RevId) VALUES ('B2')
    END

    IF @c <= 100
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Table (RevId) VALUES ('C3')
    END

    IF @c <= 400
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Table (RevId) VALUES ('D4')
    END

    IF @c <= 1
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Table (RevId) VALUES ('E5')
    END

    SET @C = @C+ 1
END

--save starting counts of test data to temp table to compare with later
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StartingCounts') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #StartingCounts
    END

SELECT
    RevId
    ,COUNT(*) as Occurences
    INTO #StartingCounts
FROM
    @Table
GROUP BY
    RevId
ORDER BY
    RevId


/************************ This is the main method **********************************/
--clear temp table that is the main processing logic
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RowNumsToChange') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #RowNumsToChange
    END

--figure out how many records there are and how many there should be for each RevId
;WITH cteTargetNumbers AS (
    SELECT
       RevId
       --,COUNT(*) as RevIdCount
       --,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) +
          --CASE
             --WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY NEWID()) <= 
                --SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) % COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)
             --THEN 1
             --ELSE 0
          --END as TargetNumOfRecords
       ,SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) +
          CASE
             WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY NEWID()) <= 
                SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) % COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1)
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
          END - COUNT(*) AS NumRecordsToUpdate
    FROM
       @Table
    GROUP BY
       RevId
)

, cteEndRowNumsToChange AS (
    SELECT *
       ,SUM(CASE WHEN NumRecordsToUpdate > 1 THEN NumRecordsToUpdate ELSE 0 END)
             OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY RevId) AS ChangeEndRowNum
    FROM
       cteTargetNumbers
)

SELECT
    *
    ,LAG(ChangeEndRowNum,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY RevId) as ChangeStartRowNum
    INTO #RowNumsToChange
FROM
    cteEndRowNumsToChange


;WITH cteOriginalTableRowNum AS (
    SELECT
       RevId
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RevId ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as RowNumByRevId
    FROM
       @Table t
)

, cteRecordsAllowedToChange AS (
    SELECT
       o.RevId
       ,o.RowNumByRevId
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) as ChangeRowNum
    FROM
       cteOriginalTableRowNum o
       INNER JOIN #RowNumsToChange t
       ON o.RevId = t.RevId
       AND t.NumRecordsToUpdate < 0
       AND o.RowNumByRevId <= ABS(t.NumRecordsToUpdate)
)

UPDATE o
    SET RevId = u.RevId
FROM
    cteOriginalTableRowNum o
    INNER JOIN cteRecordsAllowedToChange c
    ON o.RevId = c.RevId
    AND o.RowNumByRevId = c.RowNumByRevId
    INNER JOIN #RowNumsToChange u
    ON c.ChangeRowNum > u.ChangeStartRowNum
    AND c.ChangeRowNum <= u.ChangeEndRowNum
    AND u.NumRecordsToUpdate > 0

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RowNumsToChange') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #RowNumsToChange
    END

/***************************** End of Main Method *******************************/

-- Compare the results and clean up

;WITH ctePostUpdateResults AS (
    SELECT
       RevId
       ,COUNT(*) as AfterChangeOccurences
    FROM
       @Table
    GROUP BY
       RevId
)

SELECT *
FROM
    #StartingCounts s
    INNER JOIN ctePostUpdateResults r
    ON s.RevId = r.RevId
ORDER BY
    s.RevId

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#StartingCounts') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #StartingCounts
    END
```

Comment: This example is very close to what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've given no rules for how you'd like the balance to operate we're left to speculate. Here's an approach that would find the most overrepresented value and then find an underrepresented value that can take on the entire overage.

I have no idea how optimal this is and it will probably run in an infinite loop without more logic.

```
declare @balance int = 125;

declare @cnt_over  int;
declare @cnt_under int;
declare @revID_overrepresented  varchar(32);
declare @revID_underrepresented varchar(32);

declare @rowcount int = 1;

while @rowcount > 0
begin
    select top 1 @revID_overrepresented = RevID, @cnt_over = count(*)
    from T
    group by RevID
    having count(*) > @balance
    order by count(*) desc

    select top 1 @revID_underrepresented = RevID, @cnt_under = count(*)
    from T
    group by RevID
    having count(*) < @balance - @cnt_over
    order by count(*) desc

    update top @cnt_over - @balance T
    set RevId = @revID_underrepresented
    where RevId = @revID_overrepresented;

    set @rowcount = @@rowcount;
end
```

Answer (score -1):

> The problem is I don't even know what you mean by balance...You say it needs to be evenly represented but it seems like you want it to be 125.  125 is not "even", it is just 125.

I can't tell what you are trying to do, but I'm guessing this is not really an SQL problem.  But you can use SQL to help.  Here is some helpful SQL for you.  You can use this in your language of choice to solve the problem.

Find the rev values and their counts:

```
SELECT RevID, COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable
```

Update @X rows (with RevID of value @RevID) to a new value @NewValue

```
UPDATE TOP @X FROM MyTable
  SET RevID = @NewValue
WHERE RevID = @RevID
```

Using these two queries you should be able to apply your business rules (which you never specified) in a loop or whatever to change the data.